GitLab CI - Merge global before_script code from included file with local before_script
In gitlab-ci.yml file I’m including another yml file which has global before_script code.
let say for example this code:
include:

project: ‘SOME_PROJECT’
file:
‘common-ci.yml’

I want to inherit the global before_script from the included file, but also add more code to the global before_srcipt, WITHOUT override it.
for example this yml file
include:

project: ‘SOME_PROJECT’
file:
‘common-ci.yml’
before_script:
echo “some more global before_script code”

this cause the included before_script to be override. I want to merge both of them.
How it can be achived?
tried to add more before_script code, expected it to be merged with the before_script code from the included file. The result is that my local before_script code override the code from the included file.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using !reference tags so you'll be able to reutilise imported configuration and extend it with new scripts. Let's see an example:
common-ci.yaml
.dependencies:
  before_script:
    - echo "Dependencies updated"

specific-ci.yaml
include:
 - local: common-ci.yaml

reusing-config:
  before_script:
    - !reference [.dependencies, before_script]
    - echo "Extra code after preparing dependencies!"

Full documentation about this feature can be found here in the documentation.

thank you for your response.
The issue here is that common-ci.yaml is have global/root before_script, I mean its not under . dependencies and not under any job.
what should be the first parameter of !reference in that case?
In that case - what needs to be send as the first parameter for the !reference ?

I'm not sure if it works for a global configuration setup but you can try and use something like this !reference [default, before_script].
